# How to retrieve the VALUES from sheet1 to sheet2 according to the NAMES?

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

On Google Sheets, how to retrieve the VALUES from sheet1 to sheet2 according to the NAMES?

[image]

Generically speaking, would be something like:

```
GET VALUE FROM sheet1 WHERE NAME = sheet2!NAME
```

I tried some uses of MATCH and VLOOKUP without success.

Edit: Here an open sheet to test:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YMUfpz-m2RmEhR1Zi_qUpdt9YtswJFOnisiZhUYZAAU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A; sheet1!A2:B; 2; 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

This is example to get value by name from sheet1 to sheet2

```
=filter(vlookup(A2:A;sheet1!A2:B;2;0);A2:A<>"")
```